# how to clone repositories from git and run maven build automatically in java

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, terminal

I want to know if it is possible to clone a repository from github and maven build this project automatically in java.

I`m writing test scripts to test if one project is compilable after created on git which requires me to do git clone and run mvn clean install.

I have tried the following code to open terminal and clone repo but it didn`t work.

```
String command= "git clone git@gitlab******/project.git"; 
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(command);
```

I wonder if I can cd to the directory where pom file is after git clone and start mvn clean install.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, you *can*, but "didn't work" isn't helpful. Most likely, you're not authenticated.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at a continious integration solution like Jenkins which can exactly do what you wish...

Comment: Sorry about the unclear description.  I`m authenticated but I cannot open terminal with the code. And I know jenkins is a good solution but for now I cannot use jenkins to complete the test, which is another bummer. I`m thinking if I can write a shell script to run all the command and using java to execute this test.sh. will that be a easier way to do it?

Comment: Don't use Java to do it. Run a simple shell script. `git clone...` and then `mvn install`.

Comment: OK. You want to make a test in Java, that checks that, right? Then write a script that fails on error and in sequence: `clone` the repo, `cd` to it and run `maven install` there. You should be able to get the result from the script if any of the commands in the script fails.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with Windows, you can use Git Bash for test this script :

1. Add to pom.xml (parent test_git_maven)

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.0</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>initialize</phase>
                   <id>clone_and_test_compile</id>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                       </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration> 
               <executable>git</executable> 
             <arguments>
               <argument>clone</argument> 
                 <argument>git@gitlab******/${module_for_test}.git</argument> 
                   <argument>../${module_for_test}</argument> 
             </arguments>
           </configuration>
    </plugin>
   ```
2. Tree : the project is automatically added as a module because `(../${module_for_test})`

   ```
    > test_git_maven/ 
                   pom.xml <= add <plugin>
                   module_for_test1 <= from clone module_for_test1
                   module_for_test2 <= from clone module_for_test2
                   module_for_test3 <= from clone module_for_test3
   ```
3. Start :

   ```
   mvn clean compile -Dmodule_for_test=module_for_test1 -f module_for_test1/pom.xml
   ```

Comment: unfortunately, I`m working on Mac. I think git bash only works on windows, right?

Comment: mac it's works git clone  git@gitlab******/${module_for_test}.git

Answer (score 1):

Okay, So I guess I figure something out. I wrote a shell scripts including all the commands I want to run. And I execute this shell script in my java program.Here is the code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    String url="git@git****/****.git";
    String name="meow***";
    String branch="meow****";

    File wd = new File("/Users/Meow/Desktop");
    System.out.println(wd);
    Process proc = null;
    try {
       proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Users/Meow/Desktop/validate.sh "+url+" "+name+" "+branch, null, wd);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (proc != null) {
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));


       try {
          String line;
          while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(line);
          }
          proc.waitFor();
          in.close();
          proc.destroy();
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }


}
```

I have tried a lot complex ways but I think Runtime.getRuntime().exec() is one of the easiest way that you can put command,environment and directory there.
Note:url,name and branch are the arguments sent to the shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look in to Apache Execute for a better control of Runtime Process.
That way, you can issue command from Java as same as you would in terminal. Hence, your process will be simply calling method.